# JavaScript: как загрузить содержимое файла?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у меня есть общедоступный файл http://site.ru/error.tpl, как загрузить его содержимое в js? или используя jquery (если это возможно), другие библиотеки просьба не предлагать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: что-то я об этом не подумал :) спасибо

не подскажете еще: в случае с css файлами, как лучше загружать и подключать стили к dom?

Comment: Как лучше не знаю, первое что приходит в голову загружать CSS потом брать библиотеку синтаксического анализа CSS вроде этой http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/ и потом вручную добавлять стили к странице.